# C programming, threads in an endless loop eventually stop

Tags: c, multithreading

I am a beginner in c coding and playing with concurrent threads using POSIX threads.

As an example I want to let it snow on the terminal. In different threads, which are invoked in an endless while-loop, at random places and with randomly chosen time difference "snow" is falling. Each thread includes a mutex-lock to properly "clean up" its way down to the ground and at the end of the while-loop a horizon is re-drawn.

The thread-handles come in shape of an array and if the snowing is running out of thread handles a counter is reset to 1 to recycle threads handles.

At first sight it works fine, but eventually - after a few minutes - it just stops snowing.
I assume it is running out of threads handles and producing no new threads anymore, because the loop seems still running.

Any idea why it stops?

P.S.: my header files contains only some simple escape codes to clear the screen and make random numbers, respectively get the console size.
'''

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "../../needful-things/needful-things.h"

// simple option to create a function by utilitizing
// terminal commands and escape sequences
#define gotoxy(x,y) printf("\033[%d;%dH", (y), (x))

void drawHorizon(void);
void * nearSnowflake(void);
void * mediumSnowflake(void);
void * farSnowflake(void);
void Snowing(void);

#define MANY 1
#define NOT_SO_MANY 5
#define A_FEW 7

pthread_mutex_t *lockStdout;

int main(void) {
int horizon = ((checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('y')/3)*2);

clearScreen();
showCursor(0);
drawHorizon();
Snowing();

//pthread_t thread1 = 0;
//pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, Snowing, NULL);
// pthread_exit(NULL);

    showCursor(1);
    return 0;
}

void drawHorizon(void) {
    int horizon = ((checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('y')/3)*2);
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('x') ; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
    gotoxy(i,horizon);
    printf("_");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
    }
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('x') ; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
    gotoxy(i,horizon + 1);
    printf("_");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
    }
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('x') ; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
    gotoxy(i,horizon + 5);
    printf("_");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
    }
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('x') ; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
    gotoxy(i,horizon + 11);
    printf("_");
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
    }
}

// near snowflake
void * nearSnowflake() {
        int horizon = ((checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('y')/3)*2);
        int place_x = (randomNumber(1, checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('x')));
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= (checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('y') - 2) ; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
        gotoxy(place_x,i);
        putc('0', stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
        msleep(50);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
        gotoxy(place_x,i);
        putc(' ', stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
//      if (i == horizon) {
//      pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
//      drawHorizon();
//      fflush(stdout);
//      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
//      }
    }
    return NULL;
}

// medium snowflake
void * mediumSnowflake() {
    int horizon = ((checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('y')/3)*2);
    int place_x = (randomNumber(1, checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('x')));
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('y') - randomNumber(1, 10); i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
    gotoxy(place_x,i);
    putc('*', stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
    msleep(150);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
    gotoxy(place_x,i);
    putc(' ', stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
//  if (i == horizon) {
//  pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
//  drawHorizon();
//  fflush(stdout);
//  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
//  }
    }
return NULL;
}

// far snowflake
void * farSnowflake() {
    int horizon = ((checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('y')/3)*2);
    int place_x = (randomNumber(1, checkAndSetConsoleDimensions('x')));
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= (horizon - 1); i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
    gotoxy(place_x,i);
    putc('.', stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
    msleep(200);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockStdout);
    gotoxy(place_x,i);
    putc(' ', stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockStdout);
    }
return NULL;
}

// Snowing
void Snowing() {
    pthread_t Snow[100];
    int j = 0, i;

    while (1) {
            i = randomNumber(1,1000);
            if (i) {
                    pthread_create(&Snow[j++], NULL, farSnowflake, NULL);
                    msleep(randomNumber(1,20));
                }
            if (i % NOT_SO_MANY == 0) {
                    pthread_create(&Snow[j++], NULL, mediumSnowflake, NULL);
                    msleep(randomNumber(1,200));
                }
            if (i % A_FEW == 0) {
                    pthread_create(&Snow[j++], NULL, nearSnowflake, NULL);
                    msleep(randomNumber(1,300));
                }
    if (!(j<100))
        j = 1;
    drawHorizon();
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

'''

Comment: Sorry for bad indentation - was not with bad intention.

Comment: For one thing, all your thread functions have the wrong signature.  They must accept an argument of type `void *`, even if they don't do anything with it.

Comment: Why threads for something as simple as this? You can do this all in a simple event loop. Threads are better for intensive processing, like making a Mandelbrot rendering with N cores where the difference between the parallel and non-parallel versions is often dramatic.

Comment: If you do want to use threads, avoid locking as often. Lock *once*, do your stuff, release the lock. Be as quick as possible inside the lock. Rattling that lock around is just asking for trouble, especially in non-trivial code bases where you end up creating deadlocks with that much fussing.

Comment: You are creating threads, but neither detaching nor joining them.  This is a form of resource leak.  Reusing the elements of the array containing the thread IDs does not cause the existing threads to be replaced; it just makes it impossible for you to reference them.

Comment: @tadman good advice. I will also do that later, but actually I read a book about pthreads and wanted to experience the behaviour of pthreads. That is the result :-) and See your point, but tried to put the lock only around the parts which write to specific spot and clean it up to keep stdout empty. maybe I could combine in a subprocedure, but I don't think this is the problem here.

Comment: Threads are often a *huge* commitment, so if you can avoid them, do it. Writing *correct* multi-threaded code is exponentially more difficult than dealing with single threaded code. Debugging a threading issue is exceptionally not fun as sometimes thread errors will manifest in a visible way long after the fault has occurred, making tracking the fault down very challenging. In short: Threads are usually a mistake. Use them *sparingly*. If you need them, think extremely carefully about how data is used and shared.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice about threads usage. I will heed it.

and about detaching/joining I had some lazy idea: If a thread ends and returns pointer to void anyway I don't need to catch or join and the handle was "free" again. I think that's the biggest mistake here (besides bad coding habits) leading to running out of resources/handles. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it is as John Bollinger mentioned in the comments. Without detaching or joining it is not possible to "recycle" a thread handle.

> pthread_detach() — Detach a thread Allows storage for the thread whose
> thread ID is in the location thread to be reclaimed when that thread
> ends. This storage is reclaimed on process exit, regardless of whether
> the thread was detached, and may include storage for thread's return
> value.

So after a while I was just running out of freely available thread handles no matter of they ended or not. Also probably bad coding habit (among others) to guess the numbers of threads needed not to run out of handles. anyway, as a learning project, I had some good takeaways from it.

it seems I could successfully circumvent the issue by detaching all threads right after creation.

```
// Snowing
void * Snowing() {
    pthread_t Snow[300];
    int j = 0, i, ret;

    while (1) {
            i = randomNumber(1,1000);
            if (i) {
                    pthread_create(&Snow[j], NULL, farSnowflake, NULL); // j instead of j++, j incremented later so that creation and detach are done for the same thread (handle)
                    ret = pthread_detach(Snow[j]); //detach so will be free when needs to be reused
                    ++j; // incrementing j after detaching
                    msleep(randomNumber(1,20));
                }
            if (i % NOT_SO_MANY == 0) {
                    pthread_create(&Snow[j], NULL, mediumSnowflake, NULL);
                    ret = pthread_detach(Snow[j]);
                    ++j;
                    msleep(randomNumber(1,100));
                }
            if (i % A_FEW == 0) {
                    pthread_create(&Snow[j], NULL, nearSnowflake, NULL);
                    ret = pthread_detach(Snow[j]);
                    ++j;
                    msleep(randomNumber(1,150));
                }
    if (!(j<300)) {
        j = 1;

    }

    drawHorizon();
    }
```